# How to express a jQuery selector containing an XML namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write my selector for jQuery. The attribute is `xlink:href` and the value is `#_SAPGUI-icons_0_s_wfwire`. I tried to construct it like this:

```
$('[xlink:href="#_SAPGUI-icons_0_s_wfwire"]')
```

I get a syntax error because of the expression `[xlink:href="#_SAPGUI-icons_0_s_wfwire"]`.

Do you have any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because of the `:` in the selector. You need to escape it using `\\`, like this:

```js
$('[xlink\\:href="#_SAPGUI-icons_0_s_wfwire"]').addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div xlink:href="#_SAPGUI-icons_000">#_SAPGUI-icons_000</div>
<div xlink:href="#_SAPGUI-icons_0_s_wfwire">#_SAPGUI-icons_0_s_wfwire</div>
<div xlink:href="#_SAPGUI-icons_111">#_SAPGUI-icons_111</div>
```